# Is it possible to aggregate different hotel bookings in one search?

Tags: online-resources, hotels, bookings

When you search for a hotel in a given period and for some reason that period is a special period, finding a hotel can be tedious. If for example the first day a hotel is full, you often will get a message that the hotels are fully booked, even if it is only on 1 or 2 days of that period.

A solution is to make multiple bookings and switch hotels during your stay. For airlines different online aggregators exist for to combine an a trip offered by multiple airlines. For hotels I haven't found a similar service.

I will be traveling to London soon and most hotels seem to be fully booked on one or two days during my stay. I could manually search for other hotels, but I am wondering if there is really no online service doing an ideal combination of different hotel bookings for me to cover all days I am somewhere.

Answer (score 5):

Based on personal experience and trying to find solutions like this there are currently none. Your best option would be to use a website such as [Kayak.com](http://www.kayak.com) and search in one day increments.  This is not ideal but it seems to be the best option.

This would be a nice feature to have however.  Good luck and enjoy your travels.

Comment: Here are some additional multisite search aggregators (similar to Kayak.com) BookingBuddy.com Momondo.com Room77.com Hoteltonight.com offers free app-only hotel booking of same-day unsold hotel inventory.